# Replace a string by character code instead of regex?

Tags: java, regex, string, character-encoding, replace

Does Java (or any other 3rd party lib) provide an API for replacing characters based on character code (within a known `Charset` of course) rather than a regex? For instance, to replace double quotes with single quotes in a given string, one might use:

```
String noDoubles = containsDoubles.replace("\"", "'");
```

However the UTF-8 character code for a double quote is `U+0022`. So is there anything that could search for instances of `U+0022` characters and replace them with single quotes?

Also, not just asking about double/single quotes here, I'm talking about the character code lookup and replacement with any 2 characters.

Comment: Personally I think `"\""` is much more clear as to what you're doing then `'\u0022'`.

Comment: In response to some of the answers that have been posted: Please don't use Unicode literals (`\uhhhh`) for characters in the U+0020 to U+007E range.  It's apparently tempting to think that they work just like other escape sequences in string or character literals (like `\n`), but that isn't the case; in Java, they're interpreted earlier and can affect the syntax.  Just for fun, try to guess in your head what this will output: `System.out.println("\u005c\u006n".length());`, then try it and see what it actually outputs.

Comment: @ajb This does not compile because of an illegal unicode escape code ("n" is not allowed): http://ideone.com/pMyNY6

Comment: @PhilippWendler Duh.  It should have been `System.out.println("\u005c\u006e".length());`

Answer (score 5):

Use the overloaded version - [`String#replace(char, char)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace%28char,%20char%29) which takes characters. So, you can use it like this:

```
String str = "aa \" bb \"";
str = str.replace('\u0022', '\'');
System.out.println(str);  // aa ' bb '
```

Answer (score 2):

Simply use the unicode literal:

```
// I'm using an unicode literal for "
String noDoubles = containsDoubles.replace('\u0022', '\'');
```

The above will work for any character, as long as you know its corresponding code.

Comment: This will not work!  `'\u0027'` will not compile, because the `\u0027` is replaced very early with a single-quote mark, thus this has the same result as putting `replace('\u0022',''');` in your code, which is syntactically incorrect.  I just tried it and the compiler rejects it.

Answer (score -1):

You can also use a regex still.  From the [Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html):

> \xhh  The character with hexadecimal value 0xhh
>
> \uhhhh    The character with hexadecimal value 0xhhhh

Hence you could write this:

```
String noDoubles = containsDoubles.replace("\\u0022", "'");
```

Comment: The above will not compile.  The compiler replaces `\uhhhh` with the actual character _very_ _early_ in its processing.  Thus, part of your statement is equivalent to `(""","'");` which is illegal because you have an unclosed quote mark.  (I tried it.)  Also, `replace` does not use regexes (`replaceAll` does).  This should work: `replaceAll("\\u0022","'");` although it seems rather heavy compared to just using `replace('"','\'');`.

Comment: @ajb Oh yeah, thanks.  I had been doing some regexes in ant files recently where you needn't escape the escape. :)