# Scala regular expressions: how to replace a BELL character (\007) in a string

Tags: regex, scala

I need to sanitize a String containing a BELL character coming from a JSON document. I don't get how to define the Regex pattern

```
import scala.util.matching.Regex

def sanitize(dirtyString: String): String = {
   val pattern = "\007" // Octal definition or other ???
   pattern.r.replaceAllIn(dirtyString, "")
}
```

Any help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try just

```
dirtyString.replace("\u0007", "");
```

This would be much faster than using regexp for such task.

See [Replace a string by character code instead of regex?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19101824/replace-a-string-by-character-code-instead-of-regex)

Comment: This will only replace one occasion.

Comment: No. It would replace each occurrence. Check yourself: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace(java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence)

Comment: I insist on replacing `replaceAll` with `replace`. There seems to be a common misunderstanding of this "All" suffix. Here is explanation: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10827872/difference-between-java-string-replace-and-replaceall/

Comment: `replaceAll` uses a regular expression.  It'll work for you, but for simple substitutions, `replace` is superior.